# Call header on specific pages

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

I am using `mpdf` for dynamic PDF generation. I am stuck in a situation were header should be called on some specific pages like if I have 10 pages then it should be called on pages 5, 6, 7 and 9.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but see below URL i think it is very help full to you

[Header in PDF page using DOMPDF in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484318/header-in-pdf-page-using-dompdf-in-php)

Or Try this

// your dompdf setup

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

// add the header
$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
$font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");

// the same call as in my previous example
$canvas->page_text(72, 18, "Header: {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}",
                   $font, 6, array(0,0,0));

$dompdf->load_html($html);
```