# How to add Baamini Font in Dompdf and also add logo in pdf

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I want to add Baamini font in Dompdf and also i want to add header and footer in dompdf
My Controller :

```
 $FileName = 'Test.pdf';
    if(isset($request->hidden_html)){$data['hidden_html']=$request->hidden_html;}
     $html = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">';
     $html.="<style>table th,table td{border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);text-align: center;padding: 10px;font-size:12px!important;}table {width: 100%;margin-bottom: 1rem;color: #212529;border-collapse: collapse;} @page {margin: 0cm 0cm;}body {margin-top: 3cm; margin-left: 2cm;margin-right: 2cm;margin-bottom: 2cm;}header {position: fixed;top: 0cm;left: 0cm;right: 0cm;height: 3cm;}footer {position: fixed; bottom: 0cm; left: 0cm; right: 0cm;height: 2cm;@font-face{font-family: Baamini;  src: url(http://projectname(example)/css/Baamini.ttf) format('truetype');}.tamilfont{font-family: Baamini!important;}</style>";
     $html .= $data['hidden_html'];

     $pdf = new Dompdf();
     $pdf->set_option('defaultFont', 'Courier');

     $pdf->load_html($html);
     $pdf->render();
     $pdf->stream($FileName, array("Attachment" => true));
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: You have asked two questions here, best to stick to one question per post to ensure the most accurate and helpful responses.

Comment: For the header/footer question, try here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7484318/264628

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Header in PDF page using DOMPDF in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484318/header-in-pdf-page-using-dompdf-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

First add your font to **vendor\dompdf\dompdf\lib\fonts**
eg:
Baamini.ttf
Baamini.ufm

Next : add a lines to **dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php**
eg:
'baamini' =>
    array(
        'bold' => $distFontDir . 'Baamini-Bold',
        'bold_italic' => $distFontDir . 'Baamini-BoldItalic',
        'italic' => $distFontDir . 'Baamini-Italic',
        'normal' => $distFontDir . 'Baamini'
    )

**Now you can use your font in PDF**

Comment: Whiel this works, it's more complicated than it needs to be. You really only need to reference the font in the stylesheet using an `@font-face` rule. See the [Unicode How-to](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo) for details.